# Clicking on Links in a Table using Protractor

Tags: javascript, click, protractor, anchor, css-tables

I have a dynamic table, whose first column consists of links. Is there any way to always click on the first element in that column?

P.S - Any solution to click on the element, without the addition of ID's to the column elements would be highly appreciated.

Edit: The Javascript code to create the first column

```
$('#list').DataTable({
  "bLengthChange": false,
  "iDisplayLength": 50,
  order: [[ 0, "asc" ]],
  data : listData,
  columns: [
    {
      data : 'entityName',
      render: function(data, type, full, meta){
        return '<a class="showLoading" href="/application/' + full.entityId + '/test">'
          + '<span class="textUnderlineBlue" title="'+ data + '">'
        + data
        + '</span>'
        + '</a>';
      }
    },
    {
      data : 'serviceExecutive',
      render: function(data, type, full, meta){
        return data;
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

I want to click on the first element in this column

Comment: Can you please post some sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
link =element(by.id('tableID')).all(by.tagName('td')).get(1).all(by.tagName('a'));
    link.click();
```

Comment: Your Welcome @Sid

Answer (score 0):

Try to locate your link by `XPath`:

```
element(by.xpath("//table//a")).click()
```

same with `CSS` selector:

```
$("table a").click()
```

This should click on the first link in a table. If it doesn't work as expected, provide with appropriate `HTML` code sample to get more suitable solution